# Should defensive copies ALWAYS be made?

Tags: java

I have a code which takes a bipartite graph as an input and returns a map with key"1" with value which is a list of "nodes in set1" and key"2" whose value is list of "nodes in set2". Now, map is mutable. In theory I should use a defensive copy for returning a map. But, in this case is it really required ? It appears an overkill.

ex:

```
class BiPartite {

   Graph graph;
   Map bipartite

   Bipartite(graph) {
      this.graph = graph;
   }

   void calcBipartite() {
     // calculate map 
   }

   Map getMap() {
     // should i make defensive copy ? Appears overkill. 
   }  
}
```

Comment: If the value you are returning is a derived information which is calculated on the fly, there is no need to make defensive copies. Are you calculating the return value of getMap every time the method is called?

Comment: Be warned that the caller already has the outside access to the internal values of this object since you don't copy `graph`, assuming `Graph` is mutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends :)

- You can document your class accordingly, specifying that the returned Map is a mutable direct view on the mutable state of the BiPartite object. I wouldn't recommend that however.
- You can wrap the internal Map with `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)` in `getMap()` *and* document that it reflects the mutable state of the BiPartite object. That can be a valid approach as long as the BiPartite object is not supposed to be threadsafe. If the client wants to keep the returned Map as a stable snaphot, she can copy it herself. If that's not needed, she can benefit from the fast wrapping operation.
- You can always return a full copy. That'd make most sense if you actually make the BiPartite object threadsafe. In that case you'll also have to synchronize all operations of the internal map (including the map copying operation!).

Basically it boils down to: Think about how the BiPartite class and its methods should be used, pick a suitable implementation for that and clearly document both the behavior of the class and the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should return a defensive copy. If you're worried about resource use, you can return a Map that is an unmodifiable view of your private map:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableMap(bipartite);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Please note that `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` is *not* a copy - just a view with all write operations disabled. Reading the (original) answer it's easy to confuse the two.

Comment: In my opinion, an immutable view is a better choice than a copy. This leaves the performance considerations in the hands of the caller; they can decide if they need to spend and space the time that creating a copy costs. If not, they essentially have a cheap copy.

Comment: @jpmc26 I disagree for most cases, because changes to the underlying collection effect the caller. This may be sometimes intended but probably in most cases not. It's a good idea when you know that you do not want to change the underlying collection anymore - otherwise I would prefer a copy rather a view.

Answer (score 2):

The word "ALWAYS" is rarely proper when explaining patterns and good programming practices. It all depends on the context.

In your case `BiPartite#getMap` method, and the class itself, are "package private" so clients (users of your code) will not be able to use it directly. If you know that you never store or return that map outside the boundaries of that package then it's pretty safe to say that you don't need to make the defensive copy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should,
Because otherwise the client can change the private field of your class making your class behave wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the conventions of your code.  I follow a convention of copying anything you want to keep. i.e. it is the callers responsibility.

This is more efficient, but is not robust if you don't know the caller will follow this convention.

Answer (score 0):

Defensive copies are a bad thing imho because most java frameworks I came across expect a getter to always return the same value and to do that fast.

If you want to be save from missbehaving clients of your code you should expose only the method calcBipartite() and let it return a newly calculated Map. The client that uses the method has to decide how the created object is used and how many times calcBipartite() is called.

If you are the only client of your code you should neither copy nor wrap.